# prestashop admin changes / file changes

Tags: php, git, prestashop, gitignore

In Prestashop, when a change takes place in a module configuration, where is located the physical change in the files directory? I ask because I use git versioning and I wan this to be accounted for, but maybe it is removed by my .gitignore.

Example: manufacturer block, I change the number of displayed manufacturers displayed. Git doesn't account for it, it says "no changes".

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All those changes depends on the module. I assume you did made changes in the module configuration at prestashop admin. in manufacturer block, the number of manufacturers displayed value is stored in the database configuration table. So GIT will say "No Changes".

Please note that prestashop stores all configuration data in the configuration table(s). So if there only single pairs of configuration (option => value) then it can be stored in configuration table, else you can create your own tables.

As it is not a direct file change, so GIT will not notice any changes, unless you modify the default value in modules/blockmanufcaturer/blockmanufacturere.php

I hope this will help.

Thank you

Comment: Thanks, it helps right. Too bad there is no way to git and git-ftp the changes from the database...

Comment: you are welcome, i dont think so if it will be possible, because git only looks to files not database. If you upload the updated database then it will show only for the db file.